# Proving that a function is differentiable and equal to a constant value for all x

Tags: continuity, functional-equations

Let $f(x)$ denote a strictly positive continuous function defined on all real numbers with the property that $f(2012)=2012$ and $f(x)=f(x+f(x))$ for all $x$. Prove that $f(x)=2012$ for all $x$.

I am trying to prove that f is differentiable before I can do $f'(x)=f'(x+f(x))$. How can I do that?
Is this the correct approach?

Comment: "positive" or "not decreasing" ?

Comment: The question says positive.

Comment: @user76836 Next time, please try to get the basic requirements right from the start. Seeing that "continuous" suddely became a requirement *just* as I'm about to post my answer is frustrating...

Comment: I am guessing that it is a requirement... I typed the question exactly as it is was in the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a counter-example to your assertion *as it was originally*. You've now added the requirement that $f$ is continuous, which invalidates this. But since I had already written this when I saw the change, I've decided to post it nevertheless $$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    2012 &\text{for $x \in \mathbb{N}$} \\
    2102 &\text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$

Obviously $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $x \in \mathbb{N}$ then $$
  f(x + f(x)) = f(\underbrace{x + 2012}_{\in \,\mathbb{N}}) = 2012 = f(x) \text{.}
$$

If $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}$  then $$
  f(x + f(x)) = f(\underbrace{x + 2102}_{\in \,\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}}) = 2102 = f(x) \text{.}
$$